# CSS canvas and navigation bar positioning

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I've a navigation  bar which is fixed position on the top,  and a canvas. The top of my canvas gets hidden behind the navigation bar. I don't want to make canvas position absolute. I've to get my canvas below the navigation bar and in the center horizontally. To center it I put it in tag center>, but I can't get it below navigation bar, How can I get it done? my style sheet:

```
 CSS
    #nav{
        position:fixed;
        margin:0px;
        display:block;
        }
    #canvas{
        text-align:center;
        background-color:transparent;
        border: 2px solid black;
        display:block;
        }
    HTML
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="IV.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <nav>


    <div id = "toolbar_effects">

    <input type="image" src="Icons/imageviewer.svg" width="50" height="50" id="Imageviewer2"class = "s">
    <input type="image" src="Icons/effect-grayscale.svg" width="50" height="50" id="grayscale"class = "s">
    </div>
    </nav>
    <center><canvas id = "canvas" width="600" height="400"><center>
    </canvas>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Show your code or atleast what you tried so far, then we can fix the errors there.

Comment: without code We can't help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set padding-top to the body. And don't use `center` tags it is deprecated. It works http://jsfiddle.net/soov7k2k/. You probably forgot to position your navbar properly! `position: fixed` is half of the work. You need to add  `top:0` and `left:0` to your navbar otherwhise it won't work. See the fiddle.

```
body {
padding-top: 100px;//Or whatever the height of your navbar is.
}
```

Comment: That moves the nav bar down by 100px :( and 100px of top of the canvas is still hidden behind the navbar.

Comment: @ShreyAnand It does work. You have to postion your navbar properly see updated answer.

Comment: Hey adding top and left to nav worked! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Use z index in css on your navigation https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Without that by default elements that are later in code are higher in structure.

Comment: I don't want to hide my navigation bar, I want to place my canvas below it

Comment: just give higher z-index to navigation and smaller to canvas give. both element need to be positioned absolute, fixed or relative for z-index to work.